# SQL join for Loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

I have beginner knowledge on SQL and I am wondering whether this is possible in SQL.

SQL query 1 >>

```
select distinct(id) as active_pod from schema_naming
```

Query 1 output >>

```
active_pod
DB_1
DB_2
... 
DB_20
```

SQL query 2 >>

```
select * from DB_1.mapping UNION
select * from DB_2.mapping UNION
....
select * from DB_20.mapping UNION
```

Due to my limited knowledge on SQL, I'm currently running #1 query first and change DB_1, DB2,.. DB_20 in query 2 everytime and run #2.

However, I was wondering whether there's way to this in one query so I don't have to manually change DB number in the #2 query and don't have to union every line.

something like this..(but not sure what to do with union)

```
select * from {
select distinct id from schema_naming}.user_map
```

It will be great if someone can shed light on this. (I'm trying to do this on Oracle SQL)

thank you in advance.

Comment: please tag oracle

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you have so many copies of the `mapping` table across databases? This seems more like a problem of bad design

Comment: @maSTAShuFu, I edited my Q so my objective is more clear. thanks for note!

Comment: @Phil - not sure why it was designed that way but unfortunately nothing that I can change at this point... thank you for looking into this though!

Comment: You might want to look into creating dynamic queries in a stored procedure / function. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, use PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
For i in (SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || ACTIVE_POD || '.MAPPING UNION' AS QUERY
FROM SCHEMA_NAMING) loop
dbms_output.put_line(i.query);
end loop;
END
```

Your queries will appear in the output window on your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to get something like this?

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || active_pod  || '.' || 'Mapping UNION'
FROM
(
select distinct(id) as active_pod from schema_naming
) as DT;
```

Comment: actually i was looking for a simple query that will return the output of entire union. I start to think that this can be only done with dynamic query but the above concatenating trick is very good to know! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a definitely a hack but it might make your life easier until a better solution is proposed. Basically use a query to generate your 2nd query, only manual edit needed would to remove the unecessary `UNION` on the final line.

```
SELECT 'SELECT * FROM ' || ACTIVE_POD || '.MAPPING UNION' AS QUERY
FROM SCHEMA_NAMING
```

Results:

```
SELECT * FROM DB_1.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_2.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_3.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_4.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_5.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_6.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_7.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_8.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_9.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_10.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_11.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_12.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_13.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_14.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_15.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_16.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_17.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_18.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_19.MAPPING UNION
SELECT * FROM DB_20.MAPPING UNION
```